# OHAttributedLabel: setLink for an URL

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to display a link like:
sitename.com/abc.html
on OHAttributedLabel. And I want to setLink for this url like:
userlink:sitename.com/abc.html

Then I click the link on label, return twice click action on UIWebView delegate, one with the URL, and the other one without URL....

I just need one click action

What shall I do?

Update:

```
////seeingUrlString = @"sitename.com/abc.html";
[_tmpContentAttributeString setLink:[NSURL URLWithString:seeingUrlString] range:hyperLinkRange];

    self.contentLabel.attributedText = _tmpContentAttributeString;


-(BOOL)attributedLabel:(OHAttributedLabel *)attributedLabel shouldFollowLink:(NSTextCheckingResult *)linkInfo
{

    CustomWebView *_customWebViewa = [[CustomWebView alloc] init];
    _customWebViewa.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    _customWebViewa.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    _customWebViewa.webView.frame = self.view.bounds;

    NSString *_url = [linkInfo.URL absoluteString];
    if (![_url hasPrefix:HTTPPrefix]) {
        _url = [HTTPPrefix stringByAppendingString:_url];
    }
    _url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", _url, Slash, NoFollow];
    [self loadWebView:_customWebViewa.webView url:_url];
     return NO;
}
```

two click actions one from OHAttributedLabel delegate, the other one I dnno where it from ...

**UPdate2:**

Actually I just need to display a link (like: sitename.com/abc.html) on OHAttributedLabel, but do not use this link, I want user can see this is clickable link and if they tap the link, the OHAttributedLabel delegate actually fire up a custom link url, custom link url is like:

userlink:sitename.com/abc.html

I want OAHAtrributedLabel treat the display url as a normal string

Answer (score 0):

In delegate method of `OAHAtrributedLabel` return `NO`.

```
-(BOOL)attributedLabel:(OHAttributedLabel*)attributedLabel shouldFollowLink:(NSTextCheckingResult*)linkInfo{
    <Do your work here>
    return NO;
}
```

**EDIT**
I couldn't run your code. SO I'm posting the code that I have worked with.

```
//forgotPasswordlabel is my OHAttributedLabel

self.forgotPasswordlabel.text = [[NSString localizedStringForKey:@"forgot_password"] uppercaseString];
self.forgotPasswordlabel.delegate = self;
    NSRegularExpression* userRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[[NSString localizedStringForKey:@"forgot_password"] uppercaseString] options:0 error:nil];
    [userRegex enumerateMatchesInString:self.forgotPasswordlabel.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,self.forgotPasswordlabel.text.length)
                             usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
     {
         // FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL is mu URL which I'm opening in my WebView
         [self.forgotPasswordlabel addCustomLink:[NSURL URLWithString:FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL] inRange:match.range]; // add it
     }];
```

ANd in delegate method

```
-(BOOL)attributedLabel:(OHAttributedLabel*)attributedLabel shouldFollowLink:(NSTextCheckingResult*)linkInfo{
    [self forgetPassword:nil]; // here I handle password reset action
    return NO;
}
```

Hee is a look at appearnce of my Label [image]

Hope it helps...

Comment: thanks for quick reply, I did return NO in OAHAtrributedLabel delegate. But still get to click action, one from OAHAtrributedLabel delegate and another one I donno where it from ...

Comment: thanks dude, see my update 2, in your case, you display a string "Forget password?" and add a custom link for this string, I can do this as well, but my case is, I need to display a link, and add custom link for this link...

Comment: I'm doing exactly same bro. see in my code [NSURL URLWithString:FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL]. FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL is macro which holds the value of url string.

Comment: thanks for your help bro, I think your code is:you have a "Forget Password?" string on the label to display right? And you add a custom link FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL for this showing string, right? But my case is, I'm gonna show a url string "yoursite.com/abc.html" on label and add this url string a custom link "userlink:yoursite.com/abc.html".

Comment: I solved this problem by another way. Still expecting answer of this problem.